# PayPalのIPNのポストバックでINVALID検証結果の対応方法

Tags: paypal

PayPalのIPNのポストバックでINVALIDの検証結果が復帰されたが、どこが問題があるのでしょうか。
既にIPNメッセージをそのままhttps://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validateに送ったのに、なにか考えられる原因は有りますか。

Comment: http://note.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/detail/n384955

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPNのポストバックでINVALIDの結果が復帰したら、基本的にポストバックで送られてきたIPNメッセージはPayPalが発送したIPNメッセージと不一致であることを意味しています。
その原因は、エンコーディングが不一致のケースは最も多いです。
マーチャントのサイト上のプログラムのエンコーディングはアカウント上のエンコーディングと不一致であれば、IPN検証結果も不一致になるはずです。

下記の手順でアカウントのエンコーディング設定を確認できます。
www.paypal.comでログインし、イアカウント->個人設定->販売ツール　で、「PayPalボタンの言語コード化」をクリックする
または、下記URLにアクセスする：
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-language-encoding
詳細オプション」ボタンをクリックする。
次の画面で表示されているエンコーディングはマーチャントのウェブサイトのエンコーディングと一致しなければなりません。
マーチャントのウェブサイトのエンコーディングはUTF-8が圧倒的に多いので、
その画面でUTF-8を選択し、保存してから、IPNポストバックを再確認してみてください。

PayPalではテクニカルサポートの部署がありますので、何かPayPal実装関連の質問や技術的な質問がありましたら、下記URLで記事を検索してみてください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/
上記URLの一番下の「お問い合わせ」リンクをクリックしてまたは下記URLをアクセスして質問を送信してください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask